# How to to deploy AWS lambda using CodePipleline?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

In this world of CICD,I have a lambda function ( written in typescript) and presently in  Github. My IDE is vscode. I can do my development and push my change's to Github. I want that when I push my changes to github, the Lambda function should be deployed to my AWS account using Codebuild and codePipeline. I can create the codestar connection. Can anyone help me with this ?

It should be simple - I push my changes, and then the Lambda should be deployed - correct ?

My google search did not give me any how to solutions ?

Appreciate your help !

Comment: If you're able to package your application using the [Serverless Application Model], an approach would be to execute SAM commands inside a CodeBuild container. The OutputArtifacts in the CodePipeline of that container could be deployed using the CloudFormation Provider in CodePipeline (i.e. `sam deploy`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a CloudFormation actions of "Create Or Update Stack".  These articles present a good examples:

https://medium.com/hatchsoftware/setting-up-ci-cd-for-lambda-functions-using-aws-codepipeline-880567769dde

https://blog.clairvoyantsoft.com/continuous-deployment-of-lambda-functions-f5d930d1937d

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/building-cicd-pipeline-lambda-function-aws-using-aliaksandr-liakh/

Comment: ty, these are helpful as I am making progress. some issues with my buildspec file but I should be figure out

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of using CodeBuild to deploy Lambda function. And you can set up a webhook for a CodeBuild project to continuously deploy new Lambda functions on every github change

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-lambda-sam-gradle.html#sample-lambda-sam-gradle.set-up-buildspec